# How do I delete "ProgramData\Kaspersky Lab"?

Tags: windows-7, file-permissions, kaspersky

My Windows 7 user profile has administrator privileges, but I can't delete `C:\ProgramData\Kaspersky Lab` folder. I see, that the folder owner is `SYSTEM` -- maybe this is the problem, but I can't change it to my account. These articles:
http://webtrickz.com/how-to-remove-kaspersky-temporary-files-to-free-up-disk-space-featured/
http://websiteconfetti.hubpages.com/hub/How-to-Delete-Kaspersky-Temporary-Files-and-Speed-Up-Your-Computer
say that I have to turn off the "self defense" in Kaspersky options, but I have uninstalled it a long ago and don't want to reinstall it.
How do I remove that folder without reinstalling?

**UPD:** checked out this article http://www.winhelp.us/ntfs-permissions-in-windows.html#acl
Disabled "read only" attributes to all folder recursively and removed `permissions inheritance` so now only two entries are in the right window here and finally I'm owner:
[image]
But still can't delete it.

**UPD2:** `C:\ProgramData\Kaspersky Lab\AVP12` is owned by me, but I can't own the `C:\ProgramData\Kaspersky Lab\AVP12` -- it belongs to `SYSTEM`. When I choose my username in the 3rd tab (about Ownership) and press `Apply`, the messagebox `Access denied` (in Russian) appears. And when I try to add my account in the 1st tab, messagebo with something same appears.

[image]

**UPD3:** The error message `Отказано в доступе` (that means `Access denied`) shows not full folder name, but trunked on the first space symbol:

[image]

Can it be the Windows bug that make it unable to change ownership?

Comment: What happens when you try to change the owner on the files by going to  `Properties > Security Tab > Advanced > Owner Tab > Edit`?

Comment: @AlexMcKenzie, see UPD2 -- it says *access denied* and that's weird, that I had success in owning the parent directory, but can't own nested one. I'll add the nested one properties screenshot. Note: I know, changing ownership is 3rd tab, I do screenshot 1st one because seems like it has more info.

Comment: `Полный доступ` means `Full access`.

Comment: Have to tried to take ownership in safe mode?

Comment: When you uninstalled Kaspersky, did you do it (successfully) via Add/Remove programs?  Are you sure there's no left-over Kaspersky services running?

Comment: @AlexMcKenzie, successfully deleted the folder in Safe mode! But now we won't know, why I couldn't change owner and isn't it a Windows filename escaping bug (

Comment: @techie007, omg, looks like it wasn't uninstalled at all -- it was just disabled in Services and there are no processes in Task manager, that look like Kaspersky.

Comment: Use the official [Kaspersky removal tool](http://support.kaspersky.com/common/service) to delete any leftovers. Report back if that solves your issue(s).

Answer (score 0):

Go to Kaspersky Application and remove uncheck Self Defense to relieve the folder from the SYSTEM control. The permission will be granted for deletion and you shall delete the folder now.